# Escape button to cancel action

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi currently i have 2 buttons, Update and Modify. Update button is set to be hidden initially.

When i click Modify button, Modify button hides, Update button appears, Textbox becomes non read only. Then Clicking update button will hide update button and modify buttons appear and textbox will be hidden and label will appear.

How can i change the code so that:

When i first click modify button, and i can get to update the textbox values and in this state if i press "ESC" button, i will hide "update" button and textbox will be read only?

The following is the current code:

```
private void ProjectnumberupdateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ProjectnumberresultLabel.Content = ProjectnumberTextBox.Text;
            ProjectnumberupdateButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            ProjectnumberTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            ProjectnumbermodifyButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            PreviousbuildversionresultLabel.Content = "" + MajorversionresultLabel.Content + "." + MinorversionresultLabel.Content + "." + ProjectnumberresultLabel.Content + "." + BuildnumberresultLabel.Content;
        }


private void ProjectnumbermodifyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ProjectnumberupdateButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    ProjectnumberTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    ProjectnumbermodifyButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

EDIT:
This is what i have done so far:

```
    private void MajorversionTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
        {
            MajorversionupdateButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            MajorversionTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            MajorversionmodifyButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    private void MajorversionmodifyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MajorversionupdateButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        MajorversionTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        MajorversionmodifyButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Keyboard.Focus(MajorversionTextBox);
        MajorversionTextBox_KeyDown(); // this is the line. i have trouble hooking this up
    }
```

sorry, i changed the project number to majorversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can write OnKeyPress Event for the window and trace the ESC button click.
Inside that you can write the logic to toggle the visibility of the controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook / handle the KeyDown event, check if the key pressed was the Escape button and make your changes to you buttons and text boxes in the code from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can set focus on text box when modify button clicked and then use KeyDown event on text box:

```
private void ProjectnumberTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
       ProjectnumberTextBox.ReadOnly = true;
       ProjectnumbermodifyButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Reniuz hi, what is meant by set focus on textbox?

Comment: Means you need to call [Focus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focus.aspx) function on your textbox ProjectnumberTextBox.Focus();

Comment: @Reniuz im having error: Error 1 'System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'KeyCode' and no extension method 'KeyCode' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: try to add KeyPress event and check pressed key like this: `if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape)`

Comment: @reniuz i found the problem. it is due to different namespace. im doing it in this way instead: `if (e.Key == Key.Escape)` anyway i have a problem. should `ProjectnumberTextBox_KeyDown()` what should be the parameter here?

Comment: My question is how you adding this event? Selecting textbox and double clicking keydown in properties/events list? it will automatically generate everything. you can see parameters in example.

Comment: @Reniuz please see edit for what i have done. i have trouble hooking up this event.

Comment: No. You doing it wrong. Follow this:  In you form designer, select textbox, open properties and switch to event list(press button with thunder icon) then find KeyDown entry and double click. After that you will have generated code like in my example.